# $n|m \Leftrightarrow m\mathbb{Z} \le n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can we prove that: $n|m \Leftrightarrow m\mathbb{Z} \le  n\mathbb{Z}$
I understand that if $m\mathbb{Z} \le  n\mathbb{Z}$ so that $m=m\cdot 1\in n\mathbb{Z}$ and then $n|m$ but I don't understand why it's true.

Comment: If you know that $m \Bbb{Z}$ and $n \Bbb{Z}$ are subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}$, then all you need to do is prove $m \Bbb{Z} \subseteq n \Bbb{Z}$. I would first suggest you think about what it means to say $n \mid m$. Then think why $mk \in n \Bbb{Z}$ for any $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Since this question is a bit old, I'm assuming that the OP understands it now.  But in general I think it's useful to indicate (with questions like this) whether the OP lacks the intuition for the proposition, or doesn't know how to represent that intuition with rigor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G $ be a group and $A,B \leq G$. If $A \subseteq B$, then $A \leq B$ (Try to prove it if you haven't already). So in this case you just need to prove that $m \mathbb Z \subseteq n\mathbb Z$.

I'll mark the proof as a spoiler just in case you want to try it yourself first:

> Let $x \in m\mathbb Z$. Then $x = mh$, for some $h \in \mathbb Z$. But $n|m$, meaning that $m = nq$, for some $q \in \mathbb Z$, so we can conclude that $x = mh = n \cdot qh \in n\mathbb Z$. So $m\mathbb Z\subseteq  n \mathbb Z$, emaning that $m \mathbb Z \leq n\mathbb Z$